# SQL-conditional joins

Tags: sql

I have a requirement to join two tables Conditionally.
For Ex:

```
T1
--Col1
--Col2
--Col3
T2
--Col1
--Col2
--Col3
```

Join T1 and T2 on Col1 from both tables, If Col1 is NULL then join T1 and T2 on Col2 from both tables.
How to achieve this?

Comment: See COALESCE().

Comment: Tags, please. MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a query like below, which uses `case` condition in `join` crtieria

```
select * 
from 
 t1 join t2 
on 
 case 
   when (t1.col1 is NULL or t2.col1 is NULL)
   then t1.col2
   else t1.col1
 end
  =
 case 
   when (t1.col1 is NULL or t2.col1 is NULL)
   then t2.col2
   else t2.col1
 end
```

Comment: What if t1.col1 is null and t2.col1 is not?

Comment: Logically correct, but performance might be poor. Might perform better based on the IF statement and two separate select statements, but that is up to OP. Also it would only check the whole column, which might not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    T1 INNER JOIN T2 
ON T1.COL1=T2.COL1 OR T1.COL2=T2.COL2
```

Comment: Needs some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are ambiguous.  What if `col1` is `NULL` in only one table?

In any case, you can specify the logic as something like:

```
select . . .
from t1 join
     t2
     on (t1.col1 = t2.col1) or
        ( (t1.col1 is null or t2.col1 is null) and t1.col2 = t2.col2)
```

The first condition will fail if either column is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Inline view. Check this query.

```
select * from
(select t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3 from table1 t1)q1,
(select t2.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3 from table1 t2)q2
where t1.col1=t2.col1 or t1.col2=t2.col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All :)

I just tot of the below query, let me know if this works.

```
Select * from
(select col1, col2, col3, coalesce(col1, col2) as join_key)q1,
(select col1, col2, col3, coalesce(col1, col2) as join_key)q1,
where q1.join_key = q2.join_key
```